# PHP/MySQL back-end

Tags: php, android, mysql

I am considered to be beginner in PHP/Back-End development, I need answers to my queries, please.

1- what is best practice for storing images and sending it to the front-end (both android and Angular) securely from server in general?

2-for business logic or constrained, do I make this constrain satisfaction checking layer in the server-side (database -triggers- or with PHP), or in the client side (front-end) or both?

3- as this application is in its beginning, a lot of features to be added are expected, what is the best design pattern for guaranteeing extensibility and modifiability?

Comment: If you're committed to learning PHP, have a look at the various [development frameworks](http://codegeekz.com/best-php-frameworks-for-developers/) out there. Find one that suits your style and needs. You may find that there's already a module that does 80% of what you want and you can add that 20% as customizations. [Laravel](http://laravel.com/) is particularly beginner friendly and has a wealth of community code available to help you solve problems.

Comment: A guide like [PHP the Right Way](http://www.phptherightway.com/) might also illuminate various options you have.

Answer (score 0):

1. Avoid storing images in the database.  For some reason a number of
   programmers get the idea this is a Good Thing(tm) ... it typically
   is not.  Depending on expected scale, use a static server (something
   like [NGINX](http://nginx.org/) would be fast) and a logical file structure on the
   server's filesystem for image storing, and the database should only
   contain the appropriate data for finding said image (e.g. URL and
   whatever metadata and ID is needed for the application).  For a
   large scale system, use a CDN instead of a single static server.
2. If I'm understanding the question correctly, do both.  The
   server-side MUST check all input, for the sake of security as well
   as functionality of the application.  The client-side should check
   input in order to save processing load on the back-end AND as part
   of good UI/UX design.
3. There's no such thing as "the best" design pattern for an *abstract* application. There is a "best design pattern" for an object, or a group of
   objects.  Once you've defined a majority of objects you expect for your
   application you can look at the larger picture.  Most web-based
   applications these days de-couple the presentation layer from the
   controller from the data itself in the [MVC (Model-View-Controller)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model%E2%80%93view%E2%80%93controller)
   pattern.

Comment: thanks a lot, for your time, effort to answer my questions.

Comment: You're welcome.  To further expound on #2, do it in PHP for the sake of the databases' security, and also in the DB for the sake of its referential integrity.  Lots of work ... ;-)